# include cond= with string search and wildcard?

Tags: mainframe

is it possible to use wildcards using substring search
within a datafile?
Something like this:

> INCLUDE COND=(106,30,SS,EQ,C'%BIOL%')

The results should be that within the defined character field
(length 30) only results come out where the word BIOL appears.
Upper code leads to an appending program.

> INCLUDE COND=(106,30,SS,EQ,C'BIOL')
> The second works only for entries where BIOL stand at the beginning.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: This isn't a JCL question, and you should edit your question and tag it with the appropriate tag for your sort product (dfsort or syncsort).  You might want to substitute the mainframe tag for the jcl tag, just for visibility.

Comment: I doubt your second comment. `INCLUDE COND=(106,30,SS,EQ,C'BIOL')` should match any record with "BIOL" (all upper case) starting anywhere between positions 106 and 132 (incl.). `SS` means substring search; there is no need for wildcard characters. Can you show some input records which you thing should match, but sort doesn't include them?

Comment: Thanks @phunsoft. Yes you are right. The only thing which led to my confusion is, that i used first: inrec fields =(106,30,TRAN=UTOL), then I used the include cond statement, so that i have a result with both, upper- a d lowercase strings within the results.